# Lat and long extents of Canadian provinces

Tags: data, latitude-longitude, canada

I'm seeking the latitude and longitude extents (i.e., extremes of lat and long) for each Canadian province. I already have Alberta and BC.  For example, Wikipedia lists Ontario's extent as 49° 00’ N, 114° 04’ W to 60° 00’ N, 139° 03’ W.

I need the same for the other provinces. I googled a variety of terms.

Comment: They are big places and have an infinite number of lat longs, are you looking for the center of each province, the capital, the perimeter? More info.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Here you are asking a very brief question that needs more information before it can become answerable.  Please be sure to specify how this relates to GIS rather than general geography.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for extreme lat and longs of each province. So northernmost/southernmost lat, Easternmost westernmost long. Thanks!

Comment: While the question is now clearer, you still have the burden of making this question GIS-relevant.

Answer (score 7):

If you load [Natural Earth data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/) into PostGIS, you can extract the extents of each province with a query:

`WITH provinces AS (SELECT name, ST_Envelope(geom) AS geom FROM ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces WHERE admin = 'Canada')
SELECT 
  name, 
  ST_XMin(geom) AS xmin, 
  ST_YMin(geom) AS ymin, 
  ST_XMax(geom) AS xmax, 
  ST_YMax(geom) AS ymax
FROM provinces;`

`name            |  xmin   | ymin  |  xmax   | ymax

---------------------------+---------+-------+---------+------
 Saskatchewan              | -109.99 | 48.99 | -101.36 | 60.00
 Alberta                   | -120.00 | 48.99 | -109.99 | 60.00
 British Columbia          | -139.06 | 48.30 | -114.03 | 60.00
 Nunavut                   | -120.68 | 51.64 |  -61.08 | 83.11
 Northwest Territories     | -136.44 | 60.00 | -101.98 | 78.76
 Yukon                     | -141.00 | 60.00 | -123.81 | 69.65
 Ontario                   |  -95.16 | 41.66 |  -74.34 | 56.86
 Québec                    |  -79.76 | 44.99 |  -57.10 | 62.59
 New Brunswick             |  -69.06 | 44.60 |  -63.77 | 48.07
 Nova Scotia               |  -66.32 | 43.42 |  -59.68 | 47.03
 Newfoundland and Labrador |  -67.80 | 46.61 |  -52.61 | 60.37
                           |  -61.50 | 47.18 |  -60.13 | 47.80
 Manitoba                  | -102.03 | 48.99 |  -88.94 | 60.00
 Prince Edward Island      |  -64.41 | 45.95 |  -61.97 | 47.06`

Comment: You have an interesting blank row there. Southeast is St Paul Island, apparently part of NS. Northwest is Île-Brion, apparently part of QC.

Comment: Yeah not sure what's up with that. The most recent Natural Earth dataset has the expected 10 provinces and 3 territories but an older version must have had that extra feature for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Open Street Map Nominatim API for Geocoding and it will return the bounding box

Example:

**Manitoba, Canada**

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Manitoba,%20Canada&format=xml&polygon=1

Response (xml)

> boundingbox="49.9971285,49.9972285,-96.8892673,-96.8891673"
>   polygonpoints="[[-96.8892173,49.9972285],[-96.889181944661,49.997213855339],[-96.8891673,49.9971785],[-96.889181944661,49.997143144661],[-96.8892173,49.9971285],[-96.889252655339,49.997143144661],[-96.8892673,49.9971785],[-96.889252655339,49.997213855339]]"

Comment: Note that this method might return more than one polygon. (With the Manitoba example above, you'll get Manitoba and Lake Manitoba.)

Comment: Another example of use: [`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=british+columbia&format=xml&polygon_geojson=1&polygon_threshold=0.1`](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=british+columbia&format=xml&polygon_geojson=1&polygon_threshold=0.1) ... (the `polygon_threshold` option saved me a bunch of messing around with too much data.) More info in the api's [documentation](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/).

Answer (score 1):

You can download Country Boundaries from Natural Earth:

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/cultural/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.zip

Found here:

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/

Comment: @john and once you have the shapes you can open them in something like QGIS. Preferably in WGS84 coordinates, but you can project if not. If they're individual files, the extent property of the layer will tell you the info you want. If one file and you don't want to save them individually, you'd need to look at finding the minimum bounding box/rectangle/geometry of each province to get the information you want.

Comment: @MartinF it means that you don't really represent Ontario (for example) as a single LAT/LON...

Comment: @MartinF true - I will revise my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at "[Extreme points of Canadian provinces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_points_of_Canadian_provinces)" from Wikipedia.

> This is a table of extreme points (north, south, east and west) of each of the provinces and territories of Canada.